# Probability for late arrival of a train

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A train is set to arrive at a certain train station at 6AM in the morning.
>   The train is practically always late. Let $T$ be the trains delay in minutes, on a random day. Vi assume $T$ to be a continuous stochastic variable with the probability distribution:
>
> $f(t) =
> \begin{cases}
> 4te^{-2t}  &,& t>0 \\[0.75ex]
> 0 &,& \text{else}
> \end{cases}$
>
> A) What is the probability that the train is more than 3.5 minutes delayed? (4 decimals)
>
> B) Given that the train is more than 3.5 minutes delayed, what is the probability of it being more than 4 minutes delayed?

Thanks for any help or pointers. Don't hesitate to point out basic mistakes or ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Exponential distributions are pretty neat to work with, but we can't give insightful answers if we don't know what you did.

Comment: Problem is I don't know where to start, or how I can actually find the given probability for 3.5 minutes or more. I tried graphing it to see if that helped, but I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: I suppose I have to find a way to find the sum of the probability of it being 0 to 3.5 minutes late, and then 1-(t(0-3.5)) or something. I hope I'm not way off

Comment: You're on the right track @HammerH but you need to use integration since this is a continuous function

Comment: Integrals was a keyword here, thank you @DavidQuinn. I will post an answer to this question a little later with my own solution.